# How to use Implicit Many to Many between IdentityUser and IdentityRole in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: c#, many-to-many, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0

I have these 2 entities.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string NationalCode { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        public DateTimeOffset DateModified { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        public CorporateTitle CorporateTitle { get; set; }

        public Department Department { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; } //* instead of IdetityUserRole
```

```
  public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; } //* instead of IdetityUserRole

    }
```

I want to Customize these 2 entities for example overriding navigation properties.
I don't want to use IdentityUserRole Class for many to many relationship between these classes.

How should I write a configuration for this type of implicit Many to Many in Identity Core?

```
 builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(appUser => appUser.Roles)
                .WithMany(role => role.Users)
                .UsingEntity<>(); // here I don't know how to config this relationship.
```

Comment: If you like or not you can't manage without IdentityUserRole table. EF will create this table for you, maybe with different name only. But  tt is better if you control it and learn how it works.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I know how to work with that table from asp.net core 2 and 3,I want to query roles and users without using UserManager class because of this I want to query simpler between these 2 tables.

Comment: It does't matter since Net5 creates this table in any case. And for your queries you don't need to use the third table if you configured the navigation properties in a right way. You will have your favorite public ICollection<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }  in this case. You need to use the third table in your queries only if you don't use primary and foreign keys. This way you will have do make all joins manually.

Comment: @sergey I see a video from the EF Core team that we can use a Join Table in addition to Implicit many to many. right now I wrote this code and I want to test it.

` builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(appUser => appUser.Roles)
                .WithMany(role => role.Users)
                .UsingEntity<IdentityUserRole<int>>
                (au=> au.HasOne<ApplicationRole>().WithMany(),
                au => au.HasOne<ApplicationUser>().WithMany());
`

Comment: @sergey https://youtu.be/BIImyq8qaD4?t=1038

Comment: Thank you, but I am an old scholl  and prefer to keep everything under control. If you really want to understand how these things are working , you can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65706128/define-relationship-in-ef-core/65712275#65712275 . Don't forget to upvote if it helps.

Comment: But I see now what do you mean. You gave me some food for thoughts. Thanks, I will try to do it another way today.

Comment: @sergey when I get some good results, I will create a demo project and push it to my GitHub, by the way, this is my Github, https://github.com/ArminShoeibi

Comment: Thanks. I certainly will check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is the configuration need for this scenario. (Skip Navigation EF Core 5)

```
 builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                        .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
                        .WithMany(r => r.Users)
                        .UsingEntity<IdentityUserRole<int>>
                        (au => au.HasOne<ApplicationRole>().WithMany(role => role.UserRoles).HasForeignKey(u=> u.RoleId),
                        au => au.HasOne<ApplicationUser>().WithMany(user => user.UserRoles).HasForeignKey(r=> r.UserId));
```

for complete source code : https://github.com/ArminShoeibi/ImplicitManyToManyIdentityCore

Comment: Awesome, if I could upvote this several times I would.  I've been trying to get this to work for days.  Nice job.  If you search around for IsInRoleAsync and RemoveFromRoleAsync do not work, you get tons of hits and nothing that actually works.  This is it.  TY.